# Recent Download

Tags: 14.04

I just downloaded ubuntu from the website & had it saved under my documents but i can't seem to figure out how to get to the next phase of it being installed & running on my laptop. Most all the instructions I've come across don't seem to mention anything other than when I reboot I should be given the option to choose to run it or windows...not sure if this is before or after the installer should be done or how it is to be done. A little help & guidance will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would start burning the download to a dvd if you want a dual boot ;)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely downloaded an .iso file.  This is a disc image intended for burning to a writable DVD using DVD burning software, most of which is capable of burning in image mode from an .iso file.  Note: you don't just copy the .iso file to a DVD, you burn the .iso in image mode to a DVD.

If you do not have a DVD burner, you can alternatively write it to a USB stick either directly (may be difficult on Windows) or [using UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Burning to DVD is a slightly easier route if you can do it.

Once you have your DVD or USB stick with bootable Ubuntu on it, you need to just figure out how to get your computer to boot from that.  Then the installer will run.